# Defining custom labels

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it possible to define a directive which creates a custom label which I can later reference on multiple locations with `\ref{...}`?

For example:

```
...
\createlabel{l-foo}{22}
...
% later in document:
In line \ref{l-foo} foo-bar. Furthermore, line \ref{l-foo}...
...
```

Should get translated into:

```
In line 22 foo-bar. Furthermore, line 22...
```

Alternatively, is there a way to define a set of predefined values somewhere in the beginning of the document (it doesn't have to be the label mechanism) so that I can later use them in the text.

Comment: `\label` refers to the last `\refstepcounter{<counter>}`. If you use your own counter like that than it isn't a problem. Numbering every line is a different challenge.

Comment: I was using the lineno package to do line numbering, but defining labels based on line numbers within figure environments doesn't work there. I would settle with defining the line numbers for the labels manually in some way - just so that if something changes, I only have to update the label definitions, and not the refs too. If there is some other, non-label related way to do it, I would be satisfied with that as well.

Comment: You could use a counter which you set to your manual value - 1 and then use `\refstepcounter{...}` followed by a `\label`. This would cause proper references I think. Also have a look on the `zref` package. It provides a wide variety of referencing features.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you really need to use `\ref`? You could just say `\newcommand{\foobar}{22}`, so that when you type `\foobar` you get 22. Of course this crude approach does not work if any references occur before the label is defined. To do it with `\ref`, try this.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is some text. \customlabel{foobar}{22}
Here is some more text \ref{foobar}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant - not only does this work, but it also creates a label inside figure environments, which can be referenced outside of them. This means that I can take lineno's directive \LineNumber and use it to generate a line number within a figure - like this: \customlabel{labelname}{\LineNumber}. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It does not work for me. I get the following error **Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.**

Comment: @Mario --- Under what circumstances? The example works fine for me.

Comment: @Ian Perhaps the reason is that I'm using KOMA...

Comment: @Mario --- I think it's the `hyperref` package. I do not know how to fix this. Ask a new question and someone will sort out the problem (or suggest an alternative solution).

Comment: This code does not function with TeX Live 2015. It issues this error message: "! Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete."

Comment: @LuísdeSousa --- It works fine on my machine with TeXLive 2015 (and 2016). I think you probably just need to delete the `.aux` file. Otherwise you should post a new question.

Answer (score 48):

I found a solution for the custom label what works with hyperref, been looking everywhere and I keep ending back to this page. (By google searching)

Solution by Ian (does **not** work with **hyperref**)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{}}}}
\makeatother
```

The reason it does not work with hyperref, is that the package change the \newlabel command so it has 6 parameters.

Modified version of Ian's answer, that works with **hyperref** package.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
   \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}} }%
   \hypertarget{#1}{#2}
}
\makeatother
```

However doing this means that the modified version **requires** hyperref package.

\hypertarget is added to make the links work when using \ref.

Comment: The second works well, but using `\customlabel{refname}{displaytext}` puts the `displaytext` also where `\customlabel` is called. Do you know how to get rid of that text?

Comment: its been a while but its in the \newcommand one of the # number is making that, you could remove one of them at the time to test out if you get what you want

Comment: @barto: The second argument to `\hypertarget` is the culprit; using `\hypertarget{#1}{}` seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen: Can you mention what the arguments to hyperref's redefined version of `\newlabel` are, or where this is documented? By the way, I am giving you a bounty for this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Kundor Werner's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160466/how-can-one-refer-to-a-part-of-an-equation is very much related to your problem.

Comment: @Kundor Thank you, sadly I had no documentation when I did it, I just tried to read the included file for hyperref to see if I could understand it, so this was what I camw up with

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I second Nick Matteo's question: do you have a reference (sic!) pointing to where the new version of \newlabel introduced in hyperref is documented?

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo No sorry. When i looked this up i just checked in the hyperref source files, and found the newlabel with overridden there.

Comment: The modified version adds a space character after the second argument for me. Writing `\hypertarget{#1}{#2}%` instead of `\hypertarget{#1}{#2}` resolved this issue.

Comment: Although the answer is correct, it must be mentioned that the reasoning is not correct. For this, it is worth reading the great contributions by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512151/117727) and [Ulrich Diez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/117727).

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Why not `\protected@write\@auxout {}{\string\newlabel {#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{}}}%`? Because then you do not need `\hypertarget` at all and you can use this label also within `\addtocontents` which is not possible with `\hypertarget`.

Comment: marli, your solutions works well but links to the previous [sub]section, not to the line with \customlabel. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Even better, if there is a way to link also like \customref{refname}{reftext} instead of \ref{refname} to have it display a different text there. My \xlabel solution below otherwise solves all this but it requires you to always use \xref for such labels. Ideally, also \ref would work with both kinds of labels, which is true for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\modulolinenumbers[255] % To switch off the showing of the numbers on margins

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. \linelabel{line:Nam}Nam arcu libero,
nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula
augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras
viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.
Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.  Aenean faucibus.  Morbi
dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.  Curabitur
auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi,
congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit
amet orci dignissim rutrum

The sentence ``Nam arcu libero'' starts at line~\ref{line:Nam}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the \linelabel directive, unfortunately, it does not work within figure environments, even if you use \internallinenumbers in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the shortest solution is to use `\def`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}

\def \lfoo {22 }

\begin{document}
    In line \lfoo foo-bar. Furthermore, line \lfoo...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{%
 \@bsphack\begingroup
 \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
 \label{#1}%
 \endgroup\@esphack
}
\makeatother
```

another example -  define custom labels for a new environment:

```
\makeatletter%
\newenvironment{myenvironment}{%
 \addtocounter{mycounter}{1}%
 \def\@currentlabel{{\thesection.\themycounter}}%  custom labelling for this environment
 %%... etc.,  other environment definitions here
}{%
%...
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please demonstrate how your solution works? You can maybe cook up a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), that is the recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand. I think this answer the question (no use of aux file)

**Edit:** as mentioned below by egreg this work only if `\ref`is called after `\createlabel`

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\createlabel}[2]{%
\@bsphack
\expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{#2}\@esphack}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
test
\createlabel{l-foo}{22} and leater \Ref{l-foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then `\Ref` can only be used after the corresponding `\createlabel` command.

Comment: @egreg as i said may be i don't undestand but it was clear for me that it will be call later no?

Answer (score 1):

**Hyperref**-proof solution (1. works with hyperref, 2. also adds hyperlinks to the \xlabel):

You can use \nameref which is part of hyperref :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\xref}{\nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xlabel[2][]{\phantomsection\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\label{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

We call $t$ {\em positive}\xlabel[positive]{pos} if $t>0$. Now ...

\bigskip

Assume that $s$ is \xref{pos}. Then ...

Recall the definition of \hyperref[pos]{positivity}

\end{document}
```

Now \xref{pos} prints "positive" with a hyperlink to the definition (xlabel). (The \hyperref above prints the customized text "positivity" instead of "positive". To produce hyperlinks without )

To avoid repetition, you can just write \emxlabel{positive}{pos} above once you define:

```
\newcommand{\emxlabel}[2]{{\em #1}\xlabel[#1]{#2}}
```

Similarly, you can use the following for itemized lists:

```
\newcommand{\itempxlabel}[1]{\item[\bf (#1)]\xlabel[(#1)]{#1}}
```

To make the [first argument] equal to the {second} if not given, use this code (or [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400339/second-optional-argument-for-newcommand-to-be-the-same-of-the-first-in-case-it-i)):

```
\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xlabel}[2][]{\phantomsection\def\@currentlabelname{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}}\label{#2}} 
\makeatother
```

More sophisticated systems are possible with packages like glossaries or acronym. [The above solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550318/defining-custom-labels-with-hyperref/550323#550323) is essentially due to Ulrike Fischer.

Benefits:

1. You can change the appearance of the \xref{pos} later on just by changing the first argument of \xlabel. (Also the other solutions have this benefit except that some of them stop working if you \usepackage{hyperref}.)
2. \xref{pos} also produces a hyperlink. By clicking it you get to the definition (\xlabel). TexShop also shows a hover (mouseover) text (the definition). I don't know how to get the hovertext to TeXStudio.

Add the following lines to your [.cwl file](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) (and restart TeXstudio) to allow for *auto-completion* of \xref label (and to include \xlabel labels etc. into that list):

```
\xref{label}#r
\xlabel{label}#l
\itempxlabel{label}#l
\emxlabel{label}#l
```

If you use the {xifthen} formulation of \xlabel, then its .cwl line shoud read

```
\xlabel[nonlabel]{label}#l
```

Comment: Thanks, works excellently well.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the only con is: you must always use \xref, you cannot use \ref for labels created by \xlabel (or the other labels created above). It would be easier if you would not have to remember, which are standard labels and which are xlabels. But I have had no problems with this "con".

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `cleveref` package, you can also use the `\crefname` command and then use an optional argument in the `\label` command.

The following example is borrowed from [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200998/221054):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}    
% provide singular and plural names of the categories "car" and "truck"
\crefname{truck}{truck}{trucks}
\crefname{car}{car}{cars}

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}\label[car]{sec:1}
\section{Section Two}\label[truck]{sec:2}
\section{Section Three}
Cross-references to \cref{sec:1,sec:2}.
\end{document}
```