# Controlling Theorem tags in Beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am writing slides which follow a textbook, and it is obviously desirable for the theorem and equation numbering to coincide with that in the text.  I have no problem `\tag`-ing equations and linking to them with `\eqref` -- the references use the correct numbering.

But when I label a theorem and link to it, the numbering does not follow that in the textbook.  E.g.,

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}[3.12]
    \label{thm:3.12}
    $A \rightarrow B$
  \end{theorem}
 \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  As was shown in Theorem \ref{thm:3.12}, \ldots
 \end{frame}
```

In that example the reference shows up as "1" instead of "3.12".  But I cannot `\tag` the theorem environment.

> How do I control the numbering/text inside `\ref`?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18192/15925 do this for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that, from the labeling-referencing mechanism point of view, you are not really numbering your structure, but just adding a simple string (which happens to be a number) using the annotation field, so \ref doesn't really have the proper string to pick up.

I'd suggest you to use the `numbered` option for the `theorems` template and then manually change the representation for the theorem counter to assign a desired value (using a macro for this saves time):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newcommand\setthm[1]{\renewcommand\thetheorem{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setthm{3.12}
  \begin{theorem}
    \label{thm:3.12}
    $A \rightarrow B$
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  As was shown in Theorem \ref{thm:3.12}, \ldots
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use the `ams style` option for the template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\newcommand\setthm[1]{\renewcommand\thetheorem{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setthm{3.12}
  \begin{theorem}
    \label{thm:3.12}
    $A \rightarrow B$
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  As was shown in Theorem \ref{thm:3.12}, \ldots
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very good.  The one adjustment I've made, which suits my taste in "type it once", is to use `\label{thm:\thetheorem}` inside each theorem rather than retyping the number each time.

Comment: Another important detail is that when you use `\newtheorem`, you must tell it to use the same counter, thusly: `\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}`.  Without that, your custom definitions won't number properly.