# Beamer: How to reference something other than a frame

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I tried a type of reference that works with classic LaTeX article
but that I can't get it to work in a beamer presentation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\newcounter{theo}
\newcommand{\theo}{  \refstepcounter{theo} \textbf{Théorème    \arabic{theo}}  }

%\resetcounteronoverlays{theo}
\newcommand{\thm}[1]{
\begin{block}{\theo}
#1
\end{block}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hello world
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\thm{\label{th1}
My first theorem
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
As precised in Theorem \ref{th1}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

In the last frame I get:  As precised in Theorem 2

where I'm looking for :   As precised in Theorem **1**

Any idea to fix that?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173601/controlling-theorem-tags-in-beamer help?

Comment: Not exactly `@samcarter`, as i want to keep the automatic numerotation with my command  `\thm` or i can't get how to adapt it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get automatic theorem numbering for free from beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 


\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}
\deftranslation[to=French]{Theorem}{Th\'eor\`eme}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Hello world
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}
    \label{th1}
        My first theorem
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
As precised in Theorem \ref{th1}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, end of the «bricolage» then. I simply need `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}` to get it work. No output with `[T1]{fontenc} ` and unicode error with `[utf8]{inputenc} `.

Comment: @Robien1 For the optional argument of `inputenc` you should choose the encoding your `.tex` file is saved in. If your file is saved using `ansinew` then this is the correct choice for you.