# Retrieve link caption of hidden label

Tags: hyperref, labels, etoolbox

What I wish to do is create a (hidden) label in which some text is stored, and retrieve the text by referencing to it, without getting an actual link. For example:

```
\customlabel{refname}{some text} \getcaption{refname}
```

should give

```
some text
```

but `some text` should not be clickable, it simply has to be text. In fact I need it in something like `\ifstrequals{\getcaption{refname}}{foo}{\dothis}{\dothat}` (provided `etoolbox`) so `\getcaption` should really return *pure* text.

In [Defining custom labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18191) it is shown how to define a hidden label with a custom link caption provided `hyperref` is not loaded: (see [Ian Thompson's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18192/35468))

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
   \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\customlabel{refname}{some text} \ref{refname}
\end{document}
```

which outputs `some text`, as desired.
But with `hyperref` loaded this doesn't work. [Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160035/35468)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
   \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}} }%
   \hypertarget{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\customlabel{refname}{some text} \ref{refname}
\end{document}
```

but this gives `some text some text`, i.e. the label is not 'hidden'. And of course `\ref` (playing the role of `\getcaption`) does not simply return `some text`, meaning that `\ifstrequal{\ref{refname}}{some text}{yes}{no}` gives `no`.

If the caption is just a number one can use `\getrefnumber` (from `refcount`) as `\getcaption`-command, but I am not aware of an alternative of `\getrefnumber` where the stored text is an arbitrary string.

**Note:** The reason why I want to use labels (or more generally, store the text in an external file) is that the stored text has to be accessible in the document *before* the position where it is stored. I.e. the text has to be stored in an external file and retrieved in a next LaTeX run. I do not want to create one file for each `\customlabel` call, since I have to use this a 1000 times and do not want 1000 auxiliary files. That's why I think using labels is the best option.

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples.

Comment: why not just `\gdef\refname{some text}` instead of `\customlabel` and then  `\refname` instead of `\getcaption` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The main problem is that the text should also be accessible _before_ it is stored (i.e. be stored in an external file and retrieved in a next LaTeX run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply using the `\ref`-`\label` mechanism?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
  \phantomsection
  \def\@currentlabel{\unexpanded{#2}}\label{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\customlabel{refname}{som\'e text} \ref{refname}
\end{document}
```

The accent is just for showing that it doesn't make problems (because of `\unexpanded`).

If you don't want a link, then use `\ref*` instead of `\ref`.

---

A version that allows checking the saved text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \def\@currentlabel{%
    \bartodo{\unexpanded{#2}}%
  }%
  \label{#1}%
}
\protected\def\bartodo#1{#1}
\newcommand{\checklabel}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\bartodo\detokenize
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\ifstrequal{\getrefnumber{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}}%
  \x{\aftergroup\@firstoftwo}{\aftergroup\@secondoftwo}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\customlabel{refname}{som\'e text} \ref*{refname}

\customlabel{newname}{text}

\checklabel{newname}{text}{YES}{NO}

\checklabel{refname}{som\'e text}{YES}{NO}

\checklabel{refname}{some text}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the saved text is just a number for a later numeric test, a much simpler approach can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
  \label{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\checklabel}[4]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\ifnumequal{\getrefnumber{#1}}{#2}}%
  \x{#3}{#4}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\customlabel{refname}{22}

\customlabel{newname}{42}

\checklabel{newname}{42}{YES}{NO}

\checklabel{refname}{22}{YES}{NO}

\checklabel{refname}{42}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine, but `\ifstrequal{\ref*{refname}}{text}{yes}{no}` gives `no` even if I used `\customlabel{refname}{text}`. It seems like `\ref*` is still returning something else than just `text`. If the text to be stored is just a number one could solve this issue by using `\ifnumequal{\getrefnumber{refname}}{22}{yes}{no}` (in fact using numbers suffices for my purpose) but it would be interesting to have a method to extract a string too.

Comment: @barto Done. ;-)

Comment: Perfect! Works also when I test the labels before the position they were created.

Answer (score 4):

The following example uses the `zref` referencing system. It defines a new property `custom`, which is set to the desired contents. `\customlabel` then stores the contents in the `.aux` file. `\customref` extracts the value in an expandable way, thus it can be used in `\ifstrequals`. An expandable version cannot make warnings, if the reference is undefined, thus this part is put into macro `\customused`, which notifies LaTeX, that the reference is actually used. If the reference is undefined a warning is printed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-base}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{custom}{}
\newcommand*{\customlabel}[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \zref@setcurrent{custom}{#2}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{custom}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand*{\customref}[1]{%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{custom}{}% last argument is default
}
\newcommand*{\customused}[1]{%
  \zref@refused{#1}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\customlabel{refname}{some text} \customref{refname}\customused{refname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is `\customused` for? Is it necessary for the code to work or is it an extra functionality? In fact `\ifstrequal{\customref{refname}}{some text}{yes}{no}` returns `no`... I'm very interested if this can be fixed because this would not only allow to compare the stored text (as in egreg's answer) but in fact do anything with it.

Comment: @barto `\customused` is explained in the answer, see the last two sentences. If you mean `\ifstrequal` from package `etoolbox`, then you have to expand `\customref` before, of course. For example, `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\customref...`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using e-TeX, you can tap into `\pdfstrcmp` for examining strings expandably:

> This is some regular text. The stored caption is some text.
>   Do: that
>   Do: this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\customlabel}[1]{\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\getcaption}[1]{\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\ifstrequal}[4]{% \ifstrequal{<stringA>}{<stringB>}{<true>}{<false>}
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}=0
    #3% #1 = #2
  \else
    #4% #1 != #2
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\customlabel{refname}{some text}% Store some text in 'refname'

This is some regular text. The stored caption is \getcaption{refname}.

Do: \ifstrequal{\getcaption{refname}}{foo}{this}{that}

Do: \ifstrequal{\getcaption{refname}}{some text}{this}{that}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But using this it is impossible to access the text before it is stored...

Comment: @barto: A crucial detail left out of your question unfortunately...

Comment: I agree, my fault.