# Change reference text of label involving macro whose name depends on macro

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing, expansion

I want to change the reference text of a label before the next page. This is can be done with multiply defining the label, but I want to get rid of the warnings.
Because labels are written to the `.aux` file at the end of each page, this is possible by taking a command as reference text and changing the command before the end of the page. (I use custom reference text, with a preamble given by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427) in [Retrieve link caption of hidden label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226590)) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{% custom reference text
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname
  \def\@currentlabel{%
    \bartodo{\unexpanded{#2}}%
  }%
  \label{#1}%
}
\protected\def\bartodo#1{#1}
\newcommand{\checklabel}[2]{% macro not used in this example, no need to read it
  \begingroup
  \let\bartodo\detokenize
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\ifstrequal{\getrefnumber{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}}%
  \x{\aftergroup\@firstoftwo}{\aftergroup\@secondoftwo}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\mycommand{A}%
\customlabel{mylabel}{\mycommand}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel}
\def\mycommand{B}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel}

\end{document}
```

which, after 2 LaTeX runs, returns `B B`, as desired. (I use `\def` instead of `\(re)newcommand` because eventually I will put this somewhere inside, with `\global`.)

Now say I want to do this two times (in reality, a 1000 times), and the label name and command name depend on some other macro, say a counter, so that the two reference texts can be edited separately:

```
%preamble as before
\begin{document}
\newcounter{mycounter}

\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{A}%
\customlabel{mylabel\themycounter}{\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{B}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
%
\stepcounter{mycounter}%
% the same:
\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{C}%
\customlabel{mylabel\themycounter}{\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{D}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
\end{document}
```

This gives `D D D D` while I'd expect `B B D D`.

What happens is that when the labels are written to the `.aux` file, the updated value of `\themycounter` is used, and not the value at the point where the label was defined.

> So I'd like to expand the second `\themycounter` in `\customlabel{mylabel\themycounter}{\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname}` without expanding `\mycommand0` (because the latter has yet to be changeable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we fix the number of `\themycounter` at the moment of the label definition in a macro `\ctr` and then use that (expanded).

```
\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\ccclabel}[1]{\customlabel{mylabel#1}{\csname mycommand#1\endcsname}}%

\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{A}%
\edef\ctr{\themycounter}\expandafter\ccclabel\expandafter{\ctr}
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{B}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
%
\stepcounter{mycounter}%
% the same:
\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{C}%
\edef\ctr{\themycounter}\expandafter\ccclabel\expandafter{\ctr}
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
\expandafter\def\csname mycommand\themycounter\endcsname{D}%
\getrefnumber{mylabel\themycounter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Also tested in my actual problem where I put all that in an environment, after adding the necessary `\global`'s.

Comment: If you shuffle the order a bit (put the `\edef{\ctr}` first), it is even a bit cleaner to replace all other `\themycounter` occurrences to `\ctr`. That needs one level less expansion.