# How to define a command to make new commands with numbers in the name

Tags: macros, formatting

I'd like to create a command which is currently beyond my capabilities so I was wondering if anyone around here could help me out.

What I'm looking to do is define a new command similar to the following:

```
\cmd{reference001}{Title}{text A}{text B}{text C}
```

This command would then create a new command called `\reference001` which would display:

[image]

However, I would also like the `\cmd` command to define other new commands that will display only the parts of the input. E.g., it should generate a `\reference001title` command that will display `Title` and a `\reference001partB` that will display `text B`, etc.

Importantly, I'd really like to have numbers in my command name (which is possible as presented in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66695/118293)). I've put together what I've tried so far below, but I'm having trouble getting rid of all errors and particularly, with getting numbers to work as part of the command names.

To accomplish this, I've also looked at defining a custom label/ref system (via [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18191/defining-custom-labels)) which would be a perfectly valid solution for my purposes too. E.g., the `\cmd` above would then create multiple labels which could be referenced as `\ref{reference001}`, `\ref{reference001partA}`, etc. However I couldn't get that to work either.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\cmd}[5]{
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{
        \textbf{#2}

        \textbf{\textit{Part A:}} #3

        \textbf{\textit{Part B:}} #4

        \textbf{\textit{Part C:}} #5
    }
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1title\endcsname{#2}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1partA\endcsname{#3}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1partB\endcsname{#4}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1partC\endcsname{#5}
}

\begin{document}

    \cmd{reference}{Title}{text A}{text B}{text C}

    \reference

    \referencepartA

    \referencepartB

    \referencepartC

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not the real error, but the first inner `\newcommmand` is a typo

Comment: A command can have numbers in it, but it can not be invoked as `\ref001`.  `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \begin{document}
\csdef{ref001}{this is a test}
\csuse{ref001}
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Can you provide a full example that would work with my MWE?

Comment: the restriction on numbers is not a restriction on `\newcommand` it is a restriction on the tex syntax with standard catcode. `\reference123` is `\reference` followed by the three tokens `1`, `2`, `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need line breaking on your text, this could be the core of the `\cmd` you might envision.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\cmd[5]{%
  \csdef{#1title}{#2}%
  \csdef{#1partA}{#3}%
  \csdef{#1partB}{#4}%
  \csdef{#1partC}{#5}%
  \csdef{#1}{%
    \Longunderstack[l]{
      \textbf{#2}\\
      \textbf{\textit{Part A}:} #3\\
      \textbf{\textit{Part B}:} #4\\
      \textbf{\textit{Part C}:} #5\strut
    }%
  }%
}
\cmd{reference001}{Title}{text A}{text B}{text C}
\begin{document}
Here is ``\csuse{reference001partB}'' and here is the full reference:

\csuse{reference001}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that that `\cmd` does not generate the main text? I'd like to ideally be able to use `\cmd` in the preamble to define everything, and reference the various components in the document.

Comment: @zephyr Sure.  Just remove the final `\csuse{#1}` from the definition.  I have edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a macro `\CallMacro` that takes advantage of 
brace delimited arguments and does the `\csname..\endcsname`-job for you
while flipping around macro arguments as needed - no fancy packages needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Put a control sequence token in place instead of the string denoting
%% its name:
%%......................................................................
%%  \CallMacro<emptiness or tokens other than braces>{<Name of Control Sequence>}
%%
%% yields:
%%
%%  <emptiness or tokens other than braces>\Controlsequence
%%
%% E.g.,
%%
%%   \CallMacro foo{bar} -> foo\bar
%%   \CallMacro{bar} -> \bar
%%   \CallMacro\newcommand*{wEirdName}[1]{Arg 1: (#1)}
%%       -> \newcommand*\wEirdName[1]{Arg 1: (#1)}
%%
\newcommand\CallMacroIII[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\CallMacro{}\long\def\CallMacro#1#{\romannumeral\CallMacroII{#1}}%
\newcommand\CallMacroII[2]{%
  \expandafter\CallMacroIII\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{0 #1}%
}%
%
\newcommand\cmd[5]{%
  \CallMacro\newcommand{#1}{%
    \vtop{%
      \hbox{\noindent\textbf{#2}\strut}%
      \hbox{\textbf{\textit{Part A: }}#3\strut}%
      \hbox{\textbf{\textit{Part B: }}#4\strut}%
      \hbox{\textbf{\textit{Part C: }}#5\strut}%
    }%
  }%
  \CallMacro\newcommand{#1title}{#2}%
  \CallMacro\newcommand{#1partA}{#3}%
  \CallMacro\newcommand{#1partB}{#4}%
  \CallMacro\newcommand{#1partC}{#5}%                 
}%
\begin{document}
\cmd{reference001}{Title}{text A}{text B}{text C}

\verb|\CallMacro{reference001}|:
\CallMacro{reference001}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CallMacro{reference001title}|:
\CallMacro{reference001title}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CallMacro{reference001partA}|:
\CallMacro{reference001partA}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CallMacro{reference001partB}|:
\CallMacro{reference001partB}

\hrulefill

\verb|\CallMacro{reference001partC}|:
\CallMacro{reference001partC}

\end{document}
```