# Second optional argument for newcommand to be the same of the first in case it is not specified

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I want to define a `\newcommand` with two argument, of which one is optional, which allow me to have the same output of the first input in the case I do not specify the second argument, while being the second argument if specified. Let make an example:

```
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\left(#1\right)} %this is just an example command

$A = a\paren{a}$
```

[image]

I want to obtain the same by doing something like (this won't work)

```
\newcommand{\mypar}[2][#1]{#2\paren{#1}}
$A = \mypar{a} = \mypar[a]{a} \neq \mypab[b]{a}$
```

[image]

I thought that inserting `#1` as default argument when the second argument was not specified would have done the job, but it didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latex format has a standard command for doubling an optional argument in this way (as used for `\section[zz]{zz}`)

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\xmypar}[2][]{#2\left(#1\right)} %this is just an example command

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mypar{\@dblarg\xmypar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mypar{a}$

$\mypar[b]{a}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: How does the `\@dblarg` acts? What is it doing?

Comment: @opisthofulax it _just_ does what you ask and nothing more, it takes a command as argument (`\xmypar` here) then checks if there is a `[` and calls `\xpypar` if there is and `\xmypar[#1]{#1}` if there is not.

Answer (score 7):

The standard `\newcommand` doesn't support it. The kernel provides `\@dblarg`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mypar}{\@dblarg\@mypar}
\def\@mypar[#1]#2{#2\paren{#1}}
\makeatletter
```

However, you can do it more robustly and easily with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mypar}{O{#2}m}{#2\paren{#1}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\left(#1\right)} %this is just an example command

\NewDocumentCommand{\mypar}{O{#2}m}{#2\paren{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\mypar{a}$

$\mypar[b]{a}$

\end{document}
```

Not that I endorse that definition of `\paren`, of course. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: How does the `\@dblarg` acts? What is it doing?

Comment: interesting edit, whatever gave you the idea:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Added before seeing your post

Answer (score 5):

You can [check for an empty argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764) in `#1` and use it to condition on displaying either `#1` or `#2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mleftright}

\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\mleft(#1\mright)} %this is just an example command
\newcommand{\mypar}[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax #2\else #1\fi\paren{#2}}

\begin{document}

$A = \mypar{a} = \mypar[a]{a} \neq \mypar[b]{a}$

\end{document}
```

The following definition is a little simpler, but also works:

```
\newcommand{\mypar}[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax #2\else #1\fi\paren{#2}}
```