# Reference custom labels of TikZ graphic in text

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, labels

I have drawn the following diagram using the `tikz` package. I need to add labels on arrows and reference them back in the text. How can I do that? I would be so grateful if someone could give feedback on this issue.

[image]

Meanwhile, the corresponding code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
 
\draw    (140,145) -- (238.59,243.59) ;
\draw [shift={(240,245)}, rotate = 225] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

\draw    (264,237) -- (377.23,98.55) ;
\draw [shift={(378.5,97)}, rotate = 489.28] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

\draw    (404,82) .. controls (444,52) and (422.5,383) .. (554.5,244) ;
\draw [shift={(554.5,244)}, rotate = 493.52] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;


\draw (122,127) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$ $};

\draw (122,124) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$A$};

\draw (248,241) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$B$};

\draw (122,133) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$ $};

\draw (382,74) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$C$};

\draw (561,226) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$D$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit and labeled the arrows, however, I'm currently not sure how to reference the arrows in the text. I'll see if I can come up with a solution to this problem. Until then, here's a cleaned-up version of your graphic. Please note that I have changed your coordinates to something smaller than they currently are as Ti*k*Z generally uses `cm` as the unit. That's why you needed to add `x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt` as an argument to your `tikzpicture` environment. If, for whatever reason, you still need those huge coordinates, feel free to change the provided code accordingly.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \node at (0,0) (A) {$A$};
        \node at (2,-1) (B) {$B$};
        \node at (4,2) (C) {$C$};
        \node at (8,0) (D) {$D$};
    
        \draw[->] (A) -- (B) node [midway, above, sloped] (AtoB) {$A\rightarrow B$};
        
        \draw[->] (B) -- (C) node [midway, above, sloped] (BtoC) {$B\rightarrow C$};
        
        \draw[->] (C) .. controls ++(1,1) and ++(-2,-2) .. (D) node [midway, below, sloped] (CtoD) {$C\rightarrow D$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: graphic1]

#### Edit

I added a method to reference the labels in the text by writing the contents to the `aux` file. Credits to Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen for this idea found in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160035/117727) thread.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
        \protected@write \@auxout {}{%
            \string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}}%
        }%
        \hypertarget{#1}{#2}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \node at (0,0) (A) {$A$};
        \node at (2,-1) (B) {$B$};
        \node at (4,2) (C) {$C$};
        \node at (8,0) (D) {$D$};
    
        \draw[->] (A) -- (B) node [midway, above, sloped] (AtoB) {\customlabel{node:AtoB}{$A\rightarrow B$}};
        
        \draw[->] (B) -- (C) node [midway, above, sloped] (BtoC) {\customlabel{node:BtoC}{$B\rightarrow C$}};
        
        \draw[->] (C) .. controls ++(1,1) and ++(-2,-2) .. (D) node [midway, below, sloped] (CtoD) {\customlabel{node:CtoD}{$C\rightarrow D$}};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    Let's reference the arrow with the identifyer \texttt{AtoB}, shall we?\\
    Here it is: \ref{node:AtoB}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with referenced label]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I truly appreciate it. It would be so great if there would be a way to refer the labels of to the arrows in the text as well.

Comment: You're welcome. PS: I just updated my answer and included a referencing method.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: Just there is a small problem. I tried to use a simpler label instead of $A\to B$, say for example $a$. But, after running the code the duplicated version of the label is displayed; in this case, I got $aa$ instead of $a$. I would be so grateful if you could give a feedback on this issue as well.

Comment: I'm happy to help. Welcome to TeX.SX, I hope you'll have a great time here our nerdy the community.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. The `#2%` in the `\newcommand{\customlabel}` macro was too much. I forgot to remove this when modifying the code to be compatible with `hyperref`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly now.