# Storing variables in aux files

Tags: auxiliary-files

Can I use a command to set a variable, then use that variable earlier in the document?

Specifically, I want grab the last revision from the *revision history* table and put that in my footers.

In my `*.tex`, I have an environment and commands for a version-history table which I use like this:

```
\begin{history}
  \version{1.0}{1 April 2020}{Initial Release}
  \version{1.1}{10 Oct 2021}{Updated chapter 2}
\end{history}
```

In my `*.cls` I currently have:

```
\pagestyle{fancy} % Imports header style
\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\@title}
...
\newcommand{\version}[3]{#1 & #2 & #3\\\hline}
\newenvironment{history}{ ... }{ ... }
```

And I am thinking of doing this:

```
\def\@revision{?}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Imports header style
\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\@title Rev\@revision}

\newcommand{\version}[3]{%
  \def\@revision{#1}%
  #1 & #2 & #3\\\hline%
}
\newenvironment{history}{ ... }{ ... }
```

But there are two problems:

1. My footers always show `?`.
2. Even if `\@revision` was updated, my version history table is not on the first page.  So I imagine it would only set the value for later pages.

Is there a way I can store my revision in `*.out` or `*.aux`?  Then my footer can use that value at the start of the document, and I'll get a rerunfilecheck if it changed since last run?

I found a promising answer [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20826) but it saves counters (which I assume are integer-only).  I'm interested in something that can handle `[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+`

Comment: It would be very helpful if you wrote a small, complete code we can copy/paste instead of censored snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally set the label if the entry coincides with the last revision number gathered at the previous run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[raiselinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{history}
 {%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}
  \hline
  Rev & Date & Reason \\ \hline
 }
 {%
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\string\lastrevisionnumber{\@revision}}%
 }

\newcommand{\version}[3]{%
  #1\gdef\@revision{#1}%
  \ifx\@revision\lastrevisionnumber
    \def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{lastrevision}%
  \fi & #2 & #3 \\ \hline
}
\newcommand{\lastrevisionnumber}{??}
\newcommand{\lastrevision}{\ref{lastrevision}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{me}
\maketitle

\begin{history}
  \version{1.0}{1 April 2020}{Initial Release}
  \version{1.1}{10 Oct 2021}{Updated chapter 2}
\end{history}

\newpage

The last revision is \lastrevision.

\end{document}
```

You can use `\lastrevision` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to adapt an answer from this solution:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160035/205379

First I define a command for setting the revision:

```
\newcommand{\setrev}[1]{%                                                       
  \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel{revision}{{#1}{\thepage}{#1}{revision}{}} }%
  \hypertarget{revision}{#1}                                                    
}
```

Then I can access the revision with `\ref{revision}`:

```
\pagestyle{fancy} % Imports header style
\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\@title Rev:\ref{revision}}
```

Then I can set the revision in my document:

```
\newcommand{\version}[3]{%
  \setrev{#1}#1 & #2 & #3\\\hline%
}
```

I do get the warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

But maybe I'll have to live with that.

Comment: A safer approach is to use `\edef\@currentlabel{#1}` and `\label`.  You can also put `\string\gdef\string\foo{#1}` into `\protected@write \@auxout`.

Comment: That sounds great.  I'm trying to find reference manuals for `\profected@write` `\@auxout`, `\newlabel`, `\edef`, `\string`, `\gdef`and `\@currentlabel`. If you don't mind writing it up as an answer or explaining what it does, I'd be happy to try it out and accept that answer.

Comment: \edef, \string and \gdef are TeX commands and can be found in the TeXbook by Knuth.  I believe the rest are covered in source2e.pdf (which should already be loaded in the docs folder).